# E: npm unable to locate assets

Tags: npm

When I run npm run dev this error appears:

```
‼ ｢copy-webpack-plugin｣: unable to locate 'app\assets' at 'C:\Users\msi\music_project\frontend\app\assets' asset main.js 670 bytes [compared for emit] (name: main) asset index.html 231 bytes [compared for emit]

WARNING in unable to locate 'app\assets' at 'C:\Users\msi\music_project\frontend\app\assets'

ERROR in main Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app/game/index.js' in 'C:\Users\msi\music_project\frontend' resolve './app/game/index.js' in 'C:\Users\msi\music_project\frontend'   using description file: C:\Users\msi\music_project\frontend\package.json (relative path: .)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: C:\Users\msi\music_project\frontend\package.json (relative path: ./app/game/index.js)
      no extension
```

Does somebody know how to fix this?